# Search for keyword in string stops when first one is found

Tags: python, keyword

I'm currently trying to search for keywords + the following word in a string/text. I want to store these keywords in an already created text file (`f`). I have wrote this code so far:

```
def keyword_extraction(text, keyword_list, f):

    temp = re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)

    for keyword in keyword_list:
        if keyword in temp:
            results = [temp[temp.index(keyword) + 1]]
            for word in results:
                f.writelines(keyword + ': ' + word + '\n')
        else:
            f.writelines('Keyword "' + keyword + '" not found\n')
```

The problem is, whenever the keyword is found, the algorithm stops. But I want to extract all of the keywords, so when they appear twice in a text, they should be written down twice. Do you have any suggestions of how I can fix that?

Example input:

```
text = "today is a sunny day dont you think? I like this day very much"
keyword_list = ['like', 'day']
```

Expected output:

```
like: this
day: dont
day: very
```

actual output:

```
like: this
day: dont
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: can you provide a sample input and output?

Comment: hey, i added an example input and output to the question

Comment: If you want to optimize your code a bit more, you could make keyword_list a set instead of a list, for O(1) time in checking if a word is a keyword

Answer (score 3):

```py
text = "today is a sunny day dont you think? I like this day very much"
keyword_list = ['like', 'day']

splitted_text = text.split()
for index, word in enumerate(splitted_text):
    if word in keyword_list:
        print(f'{word}: {splitted_text[index+1]}')
```

Output:

```
day: dont
like: this
day: very
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by looping and removing the first occurrence of each keyword found from the list being searched until no more are left.

```
import re

def keyword_extraction(text, keyword_list, f):
    temp = re.findall(r"[\w']+", text)

    for keyword in keyword_list:
        found = False
        while keyword in temp:
            found = True
            try:
                next_word = temp[temp.index(keyword) + 1]
            except IndexError:
                next_word = ''
            f.writelines(keyword + ': ' + next_word + '\n')
            temp.remove(keyword)
        if not found:
            f.writelines('Keyword "' + keyword + '" not found\n')

text = "today is a sunny day dont you think? I like this day very much"
keyword_list = ['like', 'day', 'much']

with open('keyword_search_results.txt', 'w') as f:
    keyword_extraction(text, keyword_list, f)

print('fini')
```